# Smart gwt tree grid with multiple columns and check box

Tags: smartgwt, treegrid

We need a Smart gwt tree grid with multiple columns and check box.

After some initial investigation it seems 
1. Treegrid can support a tree for single columns and can support checkbox. But this is only for single column.
2. Treegrid can support multiple columns with datasource. However checkbox based selection is not supported..

Any suggestions on what component to use  for this requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Both features work together.  Take any multi-column tree sample, eg this one:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_appearance_multicolumns

and just call

```
employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

Comment: please tell how to get all the nodes which are checked.

Comment: TreeGrid.getSelectedRecords()